# Worksheet.Protect does not always apply the password

Tags: vba, passwords, excel-2016

On **Excel 2016**, I would like to add a button in the Quick Access Toolbar that will toggle Protect/Unprotect the active worksheet, using always the same password.

I created an xlam file containing the following macro:

```
Sub Protection()
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TEST"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TEST"
    End If
End Sub
```

It seems to work fine at first.
But when I do the following:

- Protect using the regular Excel ribbon button with no password
- Unprotect using the macro (it works even if no password is required and I think that's where the problem is)
- Protect using the macro
- Unprotect using the regular Excel button: No password is requested!!!

The following code seems to do the trick:

```
Sub Protection()
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TEST"
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox ("The password is not the usual one.")
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TEST"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

However, it doesn't seem clean.
I have this problem on my work computer (Excel 2016) but it seems OK on my personal computer (Excel 365).

Is there a better way to make sure the correct protection is applied, whatever the user has done previously on the file?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Excel 2016 that has been fixed in later version. You've found a workaround that does what you want. I recommend against using passwords when protecting sheets - it gives a false sense of security. If I can open an Excel file, I can get around any password protection in it - it's easy to find out how on the internet.

Comment: Actually this password protection is not meant to secure the file. I protect the sheet to lock a range of cells to show the user what is or is not supposed to be edited. But it's too easy to remove it, even for a casual user. But no one will attempt to edit the xml file to remove the password, it's not worth it. But yes, the workaround will do, I guess.